listdir() path object python
not sure how to fill in the path object. Leaving it blank is current directory. How to change to a different directory to list on current drive. If not on current drive how to change the path object correctly so that python os.listdir() works. I have tried ../ does not work, tried just listing directory names starting at the highest level and down to the directory I want to list. To change drives the drive letter does not work.
I am on a window10pro machine.
Ok as i said prior.  I have tried ../ to move up a directory and I have tried including the drive name and that is not excepted either.
